# Does the Dell XPS One 27 Touch Support SLAT for Windows 8 64-bit Hyper-V?

Tags: windows, windows-8, virtualization, hyper-v, dell-xps

64-bit Windows 8 has Hyper-V (virtualization) built-in.

Hyper-V only works if the host machine is equipped with a 64-bit processor that supports a feature called Second Level Address Translation (SLAT). [SLAT may also be known as extended page tables (EPT), Rapid Virtualization Indexing (RVI) and nested page tables (NPT)].

Does the "Dell XPS One 27 Touch" PC with i7 processor released in Q4 2012 support SLAT so that you can use the Hyper-V feature built-in to Windows 8?

** Note:  I should have mentioned that I do not have this system and can't personally check it.

The processor in question does support SLAT/EPT because it has the [i7-3700S processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/65524/Intel-Core-i7-3770S-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz?q=i7-3770s). Still concerned about the potential BIOS/Setup dependency though at the overall system level.

When looking through the [owners manual](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/xpsone2710/en/OM/XPS_One_2710_OM.pdf) for this machine I do NOT see a specific setting to enable SLAT/EPT (unless it is named yet again something else in the Dell setup screen). So I was hoping someone who has the machine could confirm Hyper-V actually works.

Comment: What exactly would you like me to check or need me to do to prove this out if there is no setting visible in the BIOS? I've put some comments on [a LinkedIn discussion](http://goo.gl/DDYpV) about how do you like Window Phone 8 Emulator where I replied about SLA? and so offer this entry.

Comment: Joe, I was unable to see your post on Linkedin but if you own this exact machine (XPS One 27 Touch with an i7) and have the WP8 Emulator running on it then that would confirm Hyper-V works on their setup.  Do you have this machine and the emulator (or any Hyper-V instance) running on it? If not, I will own it soon and confirm it/update this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [both](http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-one-27-2710-aio/pd) Dell XPS One 27 Touch models support SLAT.

(first one has a [i5-3330s](http://ark.intel.com/products/65510/Intel-Core-i5-3330S-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz#infosectionadvancedtechnologies), the other one has a
[i5-3450S](http://ark.intel.com/products/65512/Intel-Core-i5-3450S-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_50-GHz#infosectionadvancedtechnologies), as you can see at the bottom of their datasheet both support EPT/SLAT)

The OP asked about [this 27inch touch model](http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-one-27-2710-aio-t/pd) with the i7-3770s specifically, but the answer is correct for both.  The OP verfied with an actual machine with Windows 8 Pro that SLAT was available.

Comment: The question is about the 27inch with an i7 but I assume the answer will be the same from the processor perspective.  Do you know if Dell needs to allow SLAT in the BIOS/Setup too in order for Windows to access it though?  Concern is chip supports but machine doesn't...

Comment: The machine in question does support EPT as well because it has the [i7-3700S](http://ark.intel.com/products/65524/Intel-Core-i7-3770S-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz?q=i7-3770s) processor (thanks for pointing to where to confirm that).  Still concerned about the potential BIOS/Setup dependency though at the overall system level.

Comment: If the chip supports it, your BIOS will. It will most probably need to be enabled (by you) in the BIOS though.

Comment: Thanks Taylor, that is my assumption and concern.  When looking through the [owners manual](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/xpsone2710/en/OM/XPS_One_2710_OM.pdf) for this machine I do NOT see a specific setting to enable SLAT/EPT (unless it is named yet again something else in the Dell setup screen).  So I was hoping someone who has the machine could confirm Hyper-V actually works.

Comment: I ordered this system.  Once I get it and confirm Windows 8 Hyper-V works I will mark this as the verified answer.

Comment: Verified on the actual machine that this answer is correct. Edited and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I have written an article on how to check over at [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/73318/how-to-check-if-your-cpu-supports-second-level-address-translation-slat/).

In summary:

- Download the coreinfo utility from SysInternals
- Then use it with the `-v` switch
- If you have an Intel Processor the results will have an asterisk in the EPT row, if you have an AMD it will have an asterisk in the NPT row.

Comment: Thank you but I don't own the system yet so I am unable to check myself.  Checking before I buy.